# How to use GridLayout in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, grid-layout

I have this code in a class called PlayFrame:

```
public void construct(FieldPanel fPanel){
    this.setTitle("Play");
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(1200,600);
    this.setSize(dimension);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    GridLayout gLayout = new GridLayout();
    this.setLayout(layout);
    score.setText("Score: " + pField.scoreValue);
//      this.add(score);
//      this.add(scoreList);
//      this.add(status);
```

As you can see, I have tried to create a new GridLayout object, but I'm not sure how to use it to display the components necessary. I need a layout with a large panel in the top left, a score list panel on the top right, and a small status label down the bottom left and a small score label down the bottom right. So, I have a few things commented out because I'm not sure if they work or exactly what they do. How can I get the PlayFrame to display fPanel, the two labels and another panel they way I need them arranged in the Frame? I just need to know how to create and use a GridLayout object. Thanks.

This is what the window should like like:

```
________________________________________________________________________________
|Play                                                                     - 0 x |
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Score List:     | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Mario: 100      | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Luigi: 50       |        
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Waluigi: 20     | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Wario: 10       |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |       
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 | 
|%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                 |    
|Status: Ready!                                                       Score: 30 |
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

The percent symbols are simply the screen where the game takes place. I hope this helps.

Comment: Have you see [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)?

Comment: Instructions unclear, got my...etc.

Comment: Start with [How to use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: By the sounds of it, I would not recommend `GridLayout` for this.  Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: +1 for ASCII art :-) ............................

Comment: So no one's going to tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

If using eclipse I found [Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) to be very useful for creating GUIs. Otherwise as others have said Oracle's website is a great place to start.